# What's is the meaning of the phrase "Read it like you've written it"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

Does the meaning of the phrase changes on its usage? If it changes, how?
I am hoping an answer based on how it changes with what people are concerned, like for an example:
1) If I have written an article, and I told you to "read it like you've written it".
So I am expecting from you that you will offer constructive criticism.
2) If someone have written an article, and later on I picked up some mistakes and told the writer to review his/her article like it has written just now.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  Could you please expand that a little, maybe give examples of what you are thinking?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: It is still not clear what your question is actually asking.

Comment: It is perfectly clear to me what is being asked. I'd give an answer if I could. I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all phrases vary in meaning according to the context. I Googled this one. There were only seven hits, the top three to this very site—not a good sign in terms of its real-world frequency. As you have given it above it seems like an imperative (a command or at least suggestion), like “drive it like you stole it!” or “say it like you mean it!” The fourth hit has the words “if we” in front of it, which changes the meaning completely, and the next after that precedes it with “if you” (and by this point we are into the howling wilderness of YouTube comments).

As a teacher of writing I tend on the contrary to urge my students to try re-reading their own material as if they had *not* written it—that is, to try to imagine the experience of a reader who did *not* know going in what it was supposed to mean.

Comment: My understanding of the phrase is that we are being urged to read the work of *others* as though we had written it. In other words with sympathy and understanding.  This is different from the norm where people read their own work in a less judgemental fashion than they do the work of others.